# Visitor returns first Item of an List as null

Tags: java, list, visitor-pattern

I want to implement a Visitor for My class `MyList`. The List itself holds Elements of the type `MyEntry`. Those Entrys hold a generic Value and a reference to the next Entry in the List.

```
public class MyEntry<E> implements Visitable {

    MyEntry<E> next;
    E o;

    MyEntry() {
       this(null, null);
    }

    MyEntry(E o) {
      this(o, null);
    }

    MyEntry(E o, MyEntry<E> e) {
     this.o = o;
     this.next = e;
    }

    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
    }
}
```

The List class

```
public class MyList<E> implements Visitable {

 private MyEntry<E> begin;

 private MyEntry<E> pos;


 public MyList() {
   pos = begin = new MyEntry<E>();
 }


 public void add(E x) {
   MyEntry<E> newone = new MyEntry<E>(x, pos.next);

   pos.next = newone;
 }


 public void advance() {
    if (endpos()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }
    pos = pos.next;
 }


 public void delete() {
    if (endpos()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }
    pos.next = pos.next.next;
 }


 public E elem() {
    if (endpos()) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }     
    return pos.next.o;
 }


 public boolean empty() {
    return begin.next == null;
 }


 public boolean endpos() { 
    return pos.next == null;
 }

 public void reset() {
    pos = begin;
 }

  @Override
  public void accept(Visitor visitor) {

      begin = pos;

      while(pos.next != null && visitor.visit(pos.o)) {
          //Move one Item forward
          pos = pos.next;

     }
}
```

I have implemented the `Visitor` interface to my `ListVisitor` class

```
public class ListVisitor implements Visitor {

  public ListVisitor() {
      }

  @Override
  public boolean visit(Object o) {
      return false;
  }
}
```

The Interface `Visitor` that will be implemented in every new Visitor that i want to create, for now i only have the `ListVisitor`

```
public interface Visitor<E> { 
   boolean visit(Object o);
}
```

And the Interface Visitable, that is implemented in every class i want to visit, in this case the MyList class and the MyEntry class.

```
public interface Visitable {
    public void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

To test the implementation of the Visitor pattern I made a Testclass that creates a new Mylist and puts some Strings in it. Next it creates a new Visitor that visits the List.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyListTest {

  @Test
  public void MyListTest() {

      MyList s = new MyList();


     s.add("Hello");
     s.add("World");
     s.add("!");

      Visitor v = new Visitor() {

          @Override
          public boolean visit(Object o) {
            System.out.println(o);
            return true;
          }
      };
      s.accept(v);
   }
}
```

Now when I run MyListTest the output is:
null
!
World

My Question now is why the first Element that the Visitor visits has a null reference in it. When i add more items to my List before creating a Visitor the output always extends, except for the first item that has been inserted into the List, it will always be null.

Comment: what is the implementation of `increaseModCount`?

Comment: That was an old Implementation of an Fail-Fast Iterator, its not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

**Visitor pattern** will not change the current code structure. It is used to add the new functionality in existing code. Classes which holds the new behaviors are commonly known as Visitors.

**The classes and objects participating in this pattern are:**

> **Visitor**: It declares a Visit operation for each class of ConcreteElement in the object structure. The operation's name and
>   signature identify the class.
>
> **ConcreteVisitor**: It implements each operation declared by the Visitor.
>
> **Element**: It defines an Accept operation that takes a visitor as an argument.
>
> **ConcreteElement**: It implements an Accept operation that takes a visitor as an argument.
>
> **ObjectStructure**: It holds all the elements of the data structure as a collection, list of something which can be enumerated and used by
>   the visitors.

```java
public abstract class Food {

    public final string Name {
        get {}
        set {}
    }

    public final Decimal Price {
        get {}
        set {}
    }

    public final int Count {
        get {}
        set {}
    }

    public Food(string name, Decimal price, int count) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Count = count;
    }

    public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}

public class Pizza extends Food {

    public Pizza(string name, Decimal price, int count) {
        super(name, price, count);
    }

    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Pasta extends Food {

    public Pasta(string name, Decimal price, int count) {
        super(name, price, count);
    }

    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public abstract class Visitor {

    public abstract void Visit(Pasta pasta);
    public abstract void Visit(Pizza pizza);

}

public class DiscountVisitor extends Visitor {

    public override void Visit(Pasta pasta) {
        var totalPrice = (pasta.Price * pasta.Count);
        byte discount = 10;
        pasta.Price = (totalPrice - (totalPrice * (discount / 100)));
    }

    public override void Visit(Pizza pizza) {
        byte discount = 0;
        if ((pizza.Count < 5)) {
            discount = 10;
        }
        else if (((pizza.Count >= 5) && (pizza.Count < 20))) {
            discount = 20;
        }
        else {
            discount = 30;
        }

        var totalPrice = (pizza.Price * pizza.Count);
        pizza.Price = (totalPrice - (totalPrice * (discount / 100)));
    }
}

public class OrderList extends List<Food> {

     public final void Attach(Food element) {
        Add(element);
    }

    public final void Dettach(Food element) {
        Remove(element);
    }

    public final void Accept(Visitor visitor) {
        this.ForEach(() => {  }, x.Accept(visitor));
    }

    public final void PrintBill() {
        this.ForEach(() => {  }, this.Print(x));
    }

    private final void Print(Food food) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FoodName: {0}, Price:{1}, Count:{2}", food.Name, food.Price, food.Count));
    }
}
```

}

```
OrderList orders = new OrderList();
orders.Add(new Pizza("pizza", 45000, 2));
orders.Add(new Pasta("pasta", 30000, 1));

DiscountVisitor visitor = new DiscountVisitor();

orders.Accept(visitor);

orders.PrintBill();
```